# Datatables remove backslash(\) characters from data

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

This is my codes to use Datatables jQuery plugin that send data via AJAX to server:

```
$('#allLessonAttachmentsTable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    "bSort": false,
    "responsive": true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'http://lms.dev/admin/getFilesList',
        data: function (d) {
            d.id = '8',
            d.type = 'App\Lesson'
        }
    },
    columns: [
        {data: 'checkbox', name: 'checkbox', "width": "20px"},
        {data: 'picture', name: 'picture', 'className': 'text-center'}
    ]
});
```

As you see, `type` parameter sent to server is contain a `\` (backslash) character. but when I retrieve it in the Laravel back-end backslash character is removed.

What is Problem and why that is removed?

Comment: See how it comes before you post. That's the reason you have got something called a Preview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript has the `\` as an escape character. You might need to use `\\` to escape it. Change your code to:

```
d.type = 'App\\Lesson'
```

In the console itself, you can see how JavaScript treats `\` and `\\`:

[image]

If the whole thing is generated by PHP, you may try using PHP's function [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to generate string friendly output.

Comment: `d.type` parameters generate with a laravel method like this : `d.type = '{!! get_class($lesson) !!}'`

Comment: @A.B.Developer You need to change the code that generates it to provide double `\` or escape the `\`s. In PHP we have a function called `addslashes()`. Why not try that?